# Incrementing a string in C

Tags: c

What happens when we try to increment a string in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foobar(char *str1, char *str2)
{
 while (*((str1++)+6) == *((str2++)+8));
}

int main(){
  char str1[] = "Hello World";
  char str2[] = "Foo Bar Bar"; 

  foobar(str1,str2);

  printf``("%s %sn",str1, str2);

  return 0;
}
```

The output was:

> Hello World Foo Bar Barn

Comment: For any array `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`. Now think about that in terms of strings.

Comment: Oh, and your function `foobar` doesn't really do anything with the strings. It might go out of bounds in the loop though so may lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: It does check the condition in the function foobar but why it didn't increment the string pointers? Please explain

Comment: But the function `foobar` *do* alter the string pointers, it modifies the *local* variables `str1` and `str2`. And as arguments are passed by value in C, it means that the function receives *copies* and only modifies those copies.

Comment: I think the strings are passed by their references and any changes made in the function would reflect on the strings str1 and str2 in the main function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you increment a pointer, it points to the next object. Since these are pointers to characters, incrementing them makes them point to the next character. Your `foobar` function just throws away the incremented values though. It doesn't return them.

Comment: David I have checked it changing the return type of the function to int and included return statement at the end, but still it shows the same result.

Comment: @Mohanapriya That's not surprising.

Comment: LOL please do explain me

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea what you are trying to do but your function `foobar` does nothing as all you do is iterate through the strings on the local variables str1 - changes to which will not be passed back to main.

Well, that's not completely true. `Foobar` could potentially run off the end of the strings and crash the way it is written now.

Comment: Tim I have changed the return type of the foobar function, but still i get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Check your printf function, there is a letter 'n' that turns 'bar' into 'barn'.

Luckily, foobar function doesnt do anything, otherwise you'd be stuck in a loop, btw. it never enters the while loop but it does increment the two pointers once. :)

Comment: yup i know that i have added the letter 'n' in the printf statement. My doubt is that even for checking the condition in the foobar fuction the string pointers are incremented but there is no change in the printed string why ? Please xplain me